# Duvida com escopo js

Tags: javascript

Sei que as declarações variáveis são todas elevada para o todo do escopo, mas fiquei com um pouco de duvida quanto a isso, o uso da palavra 'use strict' evita q declarar variáveis assim

```
a = 10
```

Mas por que nessa situação abaixo ele permite mostrar o valor de this na função mesmo que com a palavra 'use strict'.

```
function foo(){
    console.log(this); 
}

"use strict";
function minhaFuncao() {
  console.log(this); //Deveria ter mostrado undefined
 }
 myFunction();
 foo();
```

Ocorreu a elevação e teria ficado assim ?

```
 function foo(){
   console.log(this);
 }

 function minhaFuncao(){
    console.log(this);
 }
```

'use strict';

Está certo o que eu estou pensando ?, ou outra coisa aconteceu, obrigado desde já

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `this` não é uma variável, é o valor correspondente ao contexto de execução de uma função. Ele está sempre presente e não pode ser declarado.

No teu caso como a função não pertence a nenhum objeto ou classe ele tem o `window` como contexto de execução.

No entanto podes limitar o valor the `this` em funções globais, ou seja onde o `this` seria o `window`. Isto tem a ver com razões de segurança, para evitar que via a consola do browser seja possível mudar valores do código.

Repara nos exemplos em baixo:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'classe';
  }
  foo() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

new Foo().foo(); // Foo {name: "classe"}

const obj = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log(this); // {foo: ƒ, name: "objeto"}
  },
  name: 'objeto'
}

obj.foo();

function foo() {
  console.log(this === window);
}

foo(); // true

function bar(){
  'use strict';
  console.log(this); // undefined
}

bar();
```

Ou seja, se a função não pertencer a um objeto ou classe, pertence ao objeto `window` por defeito mas podes limitar o acesso global usando o `use strict`.

Comment: Entendi então no caso depende do contexto em que o this é empregado, mas o uso do use strict não evitaria iso ? ou eu estou errado ?

Comment: Caro @Diogosouza ele explicou, this nao é variavel, e outra coisa use strict nao muda um "comportamento inteiro", muda apenas o comportamento para coisas "estritas", como evitar objetos com chaves duplicatas, evitar setar variaveis "nao definidas" e coisas assim. This continuará sendo um "contexto"

Comment: @Diogosouza podes limitar o valor de `this`, juntei mais informação na resposta, à pouco estava com pressa. O uso de `use strict` não evita o uso de `this` mas sim, limita-o no caso de o contexto de execução ser global.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado